# Sql group join with all fields individually

Tags: mysql

Bellow is my mysql table structure and i want result like last table format.
please give me or hint me regarding this sql query or solution.

i try to some group or order query but not getting look that.

```
tbl_id  sub_id  num1  num2  date
     2       6   100     0  2017-09-21
     3       6     0  1000  2017-09-20
```

Actually I want

```
sub_id  num1  num1-date  num2  num2-date
     6   100  2017-09-21 1000  2017-09-20
```

Comment: Question is not clear or I think table structure is not properly designed. Can you explain your  structure in brief?

Comment: Based on available information, this is not possible.

Comment: Any Other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT x.sub_id
     , MAX(x.num1) num1
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.num1 <> 0 THEN x.date END) num1_date
     , MAX(x.num2) num2
     , MAX(CASE WHEN x.num2 <> 0 THEN x.date END) num2_date 
  FROM my_table x 
 GROUP 
    BY x.sub_id;
```

But, generally, I think it's best to resolve issues of data display such as this in application code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear.

From what I understand, here is something you could try:

```
SELECT sub_id,num1,date AS num1-date FROM yourtable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT num2, date AS num2-date from yourtable WHERE num2>0) USING(sub_id) 
WHERE num1>0;
```

This will join positive num1 and date1 with positive num2 and date2 for each sub_id.

This solution assumes that there is only one entry with a positive num1 and one entry with a positive num2 for each sub_id.

Comment: Getting Error : #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias